# Can I get total number of selected option with Autocomplete from material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'd like to display the total number of selected options with the `Autocomplete` component from material-ui.

How can I do it?

Click `Open menu dropdown` > open the `Autocomplete` > select options > user will see the total number of selected options next to `Selected:X`

`X` will be the number.

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-moon-xuxnd4?file=/demo.js)

```
export default function ClickAway() {
  const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2"];

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);
  const handleValidation = () => {
    console.log("select at least one");
  };
  const clearIcon = <DeleteIcon onClick={handleValidation} fontSize="small" />;

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const handleClickAway = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
        <Box sx={{ position: "relative" }}>
          <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
              Open menu dropdown
            </button>
          </div>
          {open ? (
            <Box sx={styles}>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <button
                    style={{
                      position: "relative",
                      zIndex: 10000,
                      top: "100px"
                    }}
                    type="button"
                  >
                    select all
                  </button>
                </div>
                <span>Selected: X</span>
                <StyledAutocomplete
                  multiple
                  id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
                  open
                  limitTags={1}
                  options={top100Films}
                  disableCloseOnSelect
                  clearIcon={clearIcon}
                  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                  renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => {
                    return (
                      <div>
                        <li {...props}>
                          <Checkbox
                            icon={icon}
                            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                            checked={selected}
                          />
                          {option.title}
                        </li>
                      </div>
                    );
                  }}
                  style={{ width: 500 }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      label="Checkboxes"
                      placeholder="Favorites"
                      InputProps={{
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        endAdornment: null
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                  PopperComponent={LabelPopper}
                />
              </div>
            </Box>
          ) : null}
        </Box>
      </ClickAwayListener>
    </>
  );
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: "Select All", value: false },
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
    year: 2003
  },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
    year: 2001
  },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
    year: 1980
  },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  {
    title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
    year: 2002
  },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  {
    title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
    year: 1977
  },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [controlled state](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) for the `Autocomplete`.

1. Add a state variable. When allowing `multiple` selections, the value will be an array.

```
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([]);
```

2. Specify the `value` and `onChange` props on the Autocomplete:

```
                  value={value}
                  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                    setValue(newValue);
                  }}
```

3. Use the `value` to determine the number selected:

```
<span>Selected:{value.length}</span>
```

Here's a modified version of your sandbox with this approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-autocomplete-nfbyyw?file=/demo.js.